# Why is this question still featured?

Tags: support, bounty

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured

So, I was rewarded with bounty yesterday, and this question appears on featured list. Why is that so? Is it some kind of bug or?

This is the question -> [What could cause a page to stop from appearing on StumbleUpon?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/96309/what-could-cause-a-page-to-stop-from-appearing-on-stumbleupon)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question appears on the "featured list" for 7 days from when the bounty is added to the question, regardless of when the bounty is actually awarded.

The bounty can be manually awarded at any time in those 7 days (although you must wait at least 24 hours from when the bounty was added, and the bounty can only be added at least 48 hours after the question was asked.).

It looks like the OP manually awarded the bounty in good time, well before the 7 days were up. (After 7 days, the bounty expires and you only get half, providing you have received 2 upvotes.)

Reference:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties

Comment: "A question appears on the "featured list" for 7 days from when the bounty is added to the question, regardless of when the bounty is actually awarded." - Actually, I'm not sure that this is true!? A question I was recently following on the "featured list", that had a bounty assigned to it, seemed to disappear from the "featured list" as soon as the bounty was assigned - which was a good 3+ days before the 7 day period was up!